# Using Two External Monitors for my MBP (E. 2015) but resolution is low on the other one

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, hdmi, displayport

I'm using my MacbookPro Early 2015 to connect two external displays. One is an Asus display connected via HDMI to HDMI, the other, is a samsung display (Both are 24 inches 1920x1080) and is connected through VGA via adaptor to my Mini Display port.

However, the Samsung monitor does not seem to use the 1080p display. I tried using the Alt/Option method and it is able to use 1920 x 1080 but the resolution is squezzed horizontally.

Any way to fix this?

PS: It also detects the display as a projector for some reason and my Asus as a TV

Answer (score 1):

If the Samsung display has other inputs, you're likely to have better luck with digital inputs (DVI or HDMI) than with analog inputs (VGA). You'll need a different Mini DisplayPort adapter for that.